# Null check a whole row during a Left Join

Tags: sql, database, join, left-join

I have the following VIEW that I get as an interface to another system. Please note that it is a View, not a Table so no I cannot change the schema and add a primary key.

```
view NODE (
    STATE varchar(255), -- can be null
    SIBLING_STATE varchar(255) -- can also be null
)
```

I then need to join this table to itself on the SIBLING_STATE column to find all the other nodes that have that state.

```
select n.STATE, n.SIBLING_STATE, ns.STATE from NODE n
left join NODE ns where n.SIBLING_STATE = ns.STATE
```

I then need to pass this upstream to other views that do group-bys and counting but all that is irrelevant for the sake of this discussion.

The problem I have is that as a secondary requirement I need to check if any sibling-records have actually been retrieved as a result of this join, yet as mentioned above, any node's `STATE` and/or `SIBLING_STATE` could be null.

```
select 
    n.STATE, 
    n.SIBLING_STATE, 
    ns.STATE,
    case when (ns.<something> is not null) then 'found' else 'not found' end as IS_FOUND 
from NODE n
left join NODE ns where n.SIBLING_STATE = ns.STATE
```

How do I actually check if the `ns` record is present? I can't null-check `ns.STATE` or `ns.SIBLING_STATE` because they could both be null themselves:

```
-- Can't do this because ns.SIBLING_STATE might be null 
case when (ns.SIBLING_STATE is not null) then 'found' else 'not found' end as IS_FOUND
-- Can't do this because ns.STATE might be null
case when (ns.STATE is not null) then 'found' else 'not found' end as IS_FOUND
```

Any ideas on how I could null-check a whole record, e.g. if I could say something like?

```
case when (recordExists(ns)) then 'found' else 'not found' end as IS_FOUND
```

Answers of any kind including dialect-specific ones (i.e. only worked in mysql/sql-server/postgresql) are appreciated.

Edit: Clarifying that this is a VIEW

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
select 
    n.STATE, 
    n.SIBLING_STATE, 
    ns.STATE,
    case when (ns.NeverNull is not null) then 'found' else 'not found' end as IS_FOUND 
from NODE n
left join From (Select *, 'A' As NeverNull From NODE) ns 
   ON n.SIBLING_STATE = ns.STATE
```

Comment: Thanks @RBarryYoung! I like this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Is it your expect? If I understand correct.

When you use `LEFT JOIN` You need to use `ON` the like two table.

```
select  
    n.STATE, 
    n.SIBLING_STATE, 
    ns.STATE,
    ns.SIBLING_STATE,
    case 
      when ns.SIBLING_STATE is null or ns.STATE  is null 
      then 'not found' 
      else 'found' 
    end as IS_FOUND 
from NODE n
LEFT join NODE ns ON n.STATE = ns.SIBLING_STATE
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47af63/2

Comment: I can't do that because ns.SIBLING_STATE could be null.

Comment: @ChoppyTheLumberjack I saw your edit question, mabye you can use `ns.SIBLING_STATE is not null or ns.STATE  is not null` be `CASE` expression condition , just like my edit answer, If that isn't your expect could you provide your expect result?:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your data structure so you have a primary key.  You don't specify the database, but typical syntax might be:

```
create table NODE (
    NODE_ID int auto_increment primary key
    STATE varchar(255), -- can be null
    SIBLING_STATE varchar(255) -- can also be null
);
```

(I arbitrarily used MySQL syntax.)

Then you can simply use that value:

```
select n.STATE, n.SIBLING_STATE, ns.STATE,
       (case when ns.nod_id is not null then 'found' else 'not found' end as IS_FOUND 
from NODE n left join
     NODE ns 
     on n.SIBLING_STATE = ns.STATE;
```

Notes:

- This seems like a very awkward step as part of the solution to a problem.  You might want to ask another question about more of the problem you are really trying to solve.
- All tables should have identity/auto-incremented/serial primary keys.
- In particular, a table should not contain columns, all of which could be `NULL` on multiple rows.  In fact, duplicate rows in tables is highly discouraged, even if the values are not `NULL`.
- `JOIN`s should always have an `ON` clause.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordon. Like I said before, I can't add a primary key because this is a view, not a table.

Comment: So why you're showing us a `create table` statement?

Comment: No, it was not me. Upvoted now. My question is to @ChoppyTheLumberjack.

Comment: @MichelMilezzi . . . My apologies, it was just a coincidence then.

Comment: @MichelMilezzi It's my mistake, sorry. I changed it now. I can't modify the schema unfortunately. It's an untouchable upstream system.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree with you that this is not a good design but when dealing with analytics of corporate data-troves as is my use-case, good design is often a luxury that was not afforded when the system was created. The question here is not about best practices which have clearly not been followed. The question is, are there any clever SQL tricks I can use to solve the problem as it is?